# Python script taking over 20 hours to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, differential-equations, odeint

I have a system of 16 coupled differential equations and I'm using the Scipy.integrate.odeint package.

The code has to run from 0 to 5 gigayears and then plots the data, the nature of the differential equations is that they are extremely oscillatory. On top of that the timestep I have used is 1e+8 or I get this constant error:

'Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.'

I'm just wondering, is there any other method I can take to make my integrator solve faster? Are there any better integration methods for large systems of coupled ODEs? The code has been running for over 20 hours now to no avail.

Comment: How could we tell without knowing what you are actually doing? Please show us some code!

Comment: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Zombie_Apocalypse_ODEINT.html

The code structure is the same as this, except there are 16 equations in the function and the integration time is 5 gigayears.

Comment: You may consider adding some timing functions to pin down which parts of the code are eating up the most computation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html from there you can look up how to optimize the specific portion of the code.

Comment: @user9159408: But you are not modelling 5 gigayears of oscillatory zombie apocalypse, are you? Your actual ODE very likely matters.

Comment: Most integrators, especially those with adaptive step size, contain heuristics or magical constants that are tuned to "humane-scaled" problems. Try to rescale your problem so that the elementary time unit is 0.1 or 1 gigayear, rescale all the components of the ODE also so that the numbers you calculate with are in a range of 1e-3 to 1e6 and if possible of mostly equal size. There is no guarantee that it helps, but it should prevent "out-of-scale" distortions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For most large systems of differential equations the main bottleneck is usually computing the derivative (the right-hand side). You probably do this purely in Python, which makes it much slower than it could be. I wrote a [Python module called JiTCODE](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode/) that speeds up the integration by hard-coding the derivative and that is particularly intended for large systems of ODEs.
- Also note that `odeint` uses LSODA which is not the most efficient method for non-stiff systems.
- The error you are getting is usually raised if the number of integration steps exceeds a certain threshold. For a long integration, this may be expected. You can control this by adjusting the parameter `mxstep`.
- `odeint` also has a maximum step size parameter that is automatically chosen in a manner I do not know. While this seems to reasonably scale with your time scale in a quick test, I cannot exclude that it doesn’t handle working with gigayears in SI units well in your case, which may cause absurdly many steps.
- Given that you work with gigayears (which hints at an astronomy, which in turn makes energy conservation likely), you should also check whether a symplectic integrator is more appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Thank you, super helpful and detailed information. Giving your package a shot now, if that still takes long I will try out a symplectic integrator which I think may solve my issue

Comment: @user9159408: Note that symplectic integrators are not generally faster or the solution for your problem. The relevant difference is that they preserve energy for Hamiltonian systems, which other integrators do not. If your system is Hamiltonian, this may be a relevant feature. Otherwise, symplectic integrators are not relevant for you.

Comment: Apologies, that was by accident, and my system is indeed hamiltonian, I started with one of the more simpler methods of integration, but realise now it's no good for my needs especially as it is non-stiff. I've read the arxiv paper associated JiTcode package and it looks promising so I will be implementing that first. Thank you for your help.